# "Now think this" is it correct to use think without its preposition here

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I came across a heading of a topic where author want me to think of a scenario, so he wrote 'now think this'

Is it correct (in formal use) to use 'think' here without 'of' or 'about'?

Answer (score 1):

If just say "think", that means "believe". Using that in the imperative is very unidiomatic, and doesn't really make sense: you can't order someone to believe something. And if you try, it's really quite presumptuous. You can say "consider this" or "think about this", however.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is unidiomatic. "Now imagine this" would be fine, though.

Comment: Seems OK to me, in context. It's perhaps unusual to order someone to think something, but if you want to do that, then "think this" is grammatical, and means something slightly different to "think on this".